# Map my web app context path to hostname in Glassfish or Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, glassfish, hostname

Is it possible to map a web application running on Glassfish with `context="MyApp1"` to www.myFirstApp.com for example and another web app in the same domain with another context path to another hostname (www.mySecondApp.com)?

#### Examples

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp1/  >> To >>  http://www.myFirstApp.com
http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp2/  >> To >>  http://www.mySecondApp.com
```

I want to bypass web app context path on my deploy-server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use a virtual server. The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggncs.html) will be useful and here's a [blog](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/2007/05/virtual-hosting-using-apache-and-glassfish/) that explains it further. Keep in mind the blog is a bit outdated but the concepts are the same.