# Can glassfish host multiple sites?

Tags: glassfish, sites

I would like to know if it is possible to have multiple sites running on glassfish. I am about to try to setup a glassfish server where different users can auto-deploy their applications and get their own folder like this:

localhost:8080/user1/application1
localhost:8080/user2/application2

or something like that. I want security also so it wont be able to have logins so that the user only can get access to his own folder... Is all this or similar possible in any way in glassfish?

Comment: Sure, check out this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860335/map-my-web-app-context-path-to-hostname-in-glassfish-or-tomcat/7861206#7861206

Answer (score 0):

Check out [virtual servers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggncs.html), which is an approach where you manage only one instance.

Another approach is to give each user their own [standalone instance](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/gkrbv.html#scrolltoc) (or cluster), although each instance will listen to its own port (such as 8080 and 8090).

Hope this helps.

Comment: So it is not necessary to make a domain for each user i create?

Comment: You don't have to, depending on what "user" means.  When an administrator logs in to a domain, they have access to administer all instances.  If you don't want this, then you'll have to use multiple domains.  If you have one administrator administering multiple instances, then each instance can have its own configuration. Administering includes deploying applications.

Comment: But how do you do that? Make one account administer multiple instances...?